# Make numbers 1-100 with only four 8s

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Make numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,.....100 using only four 8s. You can use multiplication, division, addition, and subtraction. No negatives. You may use exponents.

**Example:**

$1 = 8 \times 8 \div 8 \div 8$

Comment: Do the exponents have to be one of the four eights or can they be any number?

Comment: And do you require exactly four 8s or just no more than 4 8s.

Comment: And, are you allowed brackets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not possible to generate all the numbers with only the give operations.
I used a computer for that.
The only ones are `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,15,16,17,19,24,32,48,56,63,64,65,72,80,87,88,89` (marked in bold).

So I took the liberty to use other functions like square root ($\sqrt{x}$), ceil ($\lceil x \rceil$), floor ($\lfloor x \rfloor$).

**1**  = $\frac{88}{88}$
**2**  = $\frac88 + \frac88$
**3**  = $\frac{88}{8} - 8$
**4**  = $\frac{8 \times 8}{8+8}$
5  = $\sqrt{8+8} + \frac88$
**6**  = $8 - \frac{8 + 8}{8}$
**7**  = $\frac{8 \times 8 - 8}{8}$
**8**  = $8 + 8 \times (8 - 8)$
**9**  = $\frac{8 \times 8 + 8}{8}$
**10** = $\frac{88 - 8}{8}$
11 = $\lceil \sqrt8 \rceil + 8-8+8$
12 = $\frac{88 + 8}{8}$
13 = $\lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor + \frac{88}{8}$
14 = $\lceil \sqrt8 \rceil + \frac{88}{8}$
**15** = $8 + 8 - \frac88$
**16** = $8 \times \frac{8+8}{8}$
**17** = $8 + 8 + \frac88$
18 = $8 + 8 + \sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}$
**19** = $\frac{88}{8} + 8$
20 = $8 + 8 + \sqrt{8+8}$
21 = $8 + 8 + \lceil \sqrt{8} \rceil + \lfloor \sqrt{8} \rfloor$
22 = $\frac{88}{\sqrt{8+8}}$
23 = $\lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil^{\lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil} - \sqrt{8+8}$
**24** = $88-8\times 8$
25 = $\lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil^{\lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil} - \sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}$
26 = $ 8 +8 +8 + \lfloor \sqrt{8} \rfloor$
27 = $\lceil \sqrt8 \rceil + 8+8+8$
28 = $8 \times \lceil\sqrt8\rceil + \sqrt{8+8}$
29 = $8 \times \sqrt{8+8} - \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil$
30 = $8 \times \sqrt{8+8} - \lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor$
31 = $\lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil^{\lceil\sqrt{8}\rceil} + \sqrt{8+8}$
**32** = $8 + 8 + 8 + 8$
33 = $8 \times \sqrt{8+8} + \lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt8} \rfloor$
34 = $8 \times \sqrt{8+8} + \lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor$
35 = $8 \times \sqrt{8+8} + \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil$
36 = $(8 + \lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt8}\rfloor) \times \sqrt{8+8}$
37 = $\lfloor\frac{88}{\lceil\sqrt8\rceil}\rfloor + 8$
38 = $\lceil\frac{88}{\lceil\sqrt8\rceil}\rceil + 8$
39 = $(8+ \lceil\sqrt8\rceil + \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor) \times \lceil\sqrt8\rceil$
40 = $8 \times \sqrt{8+8} + 8$
41 = $\frac{88}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor} - \lceil\sqrt8\rceil$
42 = $\frac{88}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor} - \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor$
43 = $\frac{88}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor} - \lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt8}\rfloor$
44 = $\frac{88}{\sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}}$
45 = $\frac{88}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor} + \lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt8}\rfloor$
46 = $\frac{88}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor} + \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor$
47 = $\frac{88}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor} + \lceil\sqrt8\rceil$
**48**  = $8 \times 8 - 8 -8$
49 = $(8 - \lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt8} \rfloor) \times (8 - \lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt8} \rfloor)$
50 = $(\lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor + \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil) \times (8 + \lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor)$
51 = $(8+8) \times \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil + \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil$
52 = $\frac{88}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor} + 8$
53 = $8 \times 8 - 8 - \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil$
54 = $8 \times 8 - 8 - \lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor$
55 = $8 \times 8 - 8 - \lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt8} \rfloor$
**56** = $8 \times (8 - \frac88)$
57 = $8 \times 8 - 8 + \lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt8} \rfloor$
58 = $8 \times 8 - 8 + \lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor$
59 = $8 \times 8 - 8 + \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil$
60 = $8 \times 8 - \sqrt{8+8}$
61 = $8\times 8 - \lceil \frac{8}{\sqrt8}\rceil$
62 = $8\times 8 - \sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}$
**63**  = $8 \times 8 - \frac88$
**64**  = $8 \times 8 \times \frac88$
**65**  = $8 * 8 + \frac88$
66 = $8\times 8 + \sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}$
67 = $8\times 8 + \lceil \frac{8}{\sqrt8}\rceil$
68 = $8 \times 8 + \sqrt{8+8}$
69 = $8 + 8 \times 8 - \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil$
70 = $8 \times 8 + \sqrt{8+8}$
71 = $8 +8 \times 8 - \lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt8} \rfloor$
**72**  = $88 - 8 - 8$
73 = $\lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt8} \rfloor + 8 +8 \times 8$
74 = $\lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor + 8 +8 \times 8$
75 = $\lceil \sqrt8 \rceil + 8 +8 \times 8$
76 = $\lceil \sqrt{88 \times 8 \times 8} \rceil$ - thanks to [h34](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55584/make-numbers-1-100-with-only-four-8s/55623?noredirect=1#comment171574_55623)
77 = $88 - 8 - \lceil\sqrt8\rceil$
78 = $88 - 8 - \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor$
79 = $\lceil\sqrt8\rceil^{\sqrt{8+8}} - \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor$
**80**  = $8\times 8 + 8 + 8$
81 = $(\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor + \lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt8}\rfloor)^{\sqrt{8+8}}$
82 = $88 - 8 + \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor$
83 = $88 - 8 + \lceil\sqrt8\rceil$
84 = $88 - \sqrt{8+8}$
85 = $88 - \lceil\frac{8}{\sqrt8}\rceil$
86 = $88 - \lfloor\frac{8}{\sqrt8}\rfloor$
**87** = $88 - \frac88$
**88** = $88 - 8 + 8$
**89** = $88 + \frac88$
90 = $88 + \lfloor\frac{8}{\sqrt8}\rfloor$
91 = $88 + \lceil\frac{8}{\sqrt8}\rceil$
92 = $88 + \sqrt{8+8}$
93 = $88 +8 - \lceil\sqrt8\rceil$
94 = $88 +8 - \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor$
95 = $88 +8 - \lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt8}\rfloor$
96 = $8 \times \sqrt{8+8} \times \lceil \sqrt8 \rceil$
97 = $88 +8 + \lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt8}\rfloor$
98 = $88 +8 + \lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor$
99 = $88 +8 + \lceil\sqrt8\rceil$
100 = $(8 + \lfloor \sqrt8 \rfloor)^{\sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}}$

**Bonus**:
If we allow `log` functions we can generate every number like this:

$x = \log_{\frac{\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt8}\rfloor}{\lfloor\sqrt8\rfloor}}\left({\log_8\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots\sqrt{8\,}\,}\,}}_\text{x square roots}}\right)$

This is equivalent to

$x = \log_{\frac12}\left({\log_8{8^{\frac{1}{2^x}}}}\right)$

Going further:

$x = \log_{\frac12}\left({\frac{1}{2^x}}\right)$

Depending on he number of square roots, we can get any number.

And the **snarky solution**:

Turn one eight 90 degrees to get: $\infty$ and then $\frac{8-8}{8} \times \infty=0 \times \infty$ which can be equal to anything. (l know, I know, you will say it's undefined, but think... limits).

Comment: Filling your first two gaps: 18 = 8 + 8 + $\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{88}}}\rceil$, 20 = 8 + 8 + $\lceil\sqrt{\sqrt{88}}\rceil$.

Comment: Filling your last gap: 100 = $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{8^8}}}}}}} * 88\rfloor$.

Comment: And now there's only one gap left to fill, 76, for which an answer is $\lceil\sqrt(8*8*88)\rceil$.

Comment: What about 100 = 88/.88 ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is doable with only additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions and exponents. This is what I managed to get:

```
1  = (8 * 8) / (8 * 8) 
2  = (8 / 8) + (8 / 8)
3  = (8 + 8 + 8) / 8
4  = (8 * 8) / (8 + 8)
5  = ?
6  = 8 - (8 + 8) / 8
7  = (8 * 8 - 8) / 8
8  = (8 ^ (8 - 8)) * 8
9  = (8 * 8 + 8) / 8
10 = 8 + (8 + 8) / 8
11 = ?
12 = (88 + 8) / 8
13 = ?
14 = ?
15 = 8 + 8 - 8 / 8
16 = 8 + 8 * 8 / 8
17 = 8 + 8 + 8 / 8
18 = ?
19 = 88 / 8 + 8
20 = ?
21 = ?
22 = ?
23 = ?
24 = 88 - 8 * 8
25 = ?
26 = ?
27 = ?
28 = ?
29 = ?
30 = ?
31 = ?
32 = 8 + 8 + 8 + 8
33 = ?
34 = ?
35 = ?
36 = ?
37 = ?
38 = ?
39 = ?
40 = ?
41 = ?
42 = ?
43 = ?
44 = ?
45 = ?
46 = ?
47 = ?
48 =  8 * 8 - 8 - 8
49 = ?
50 = ?
51 = ?
52 = ?
53 = ?
54 = ?
55 = ?
56 = (8 - 8 / 8) * 8
57 = ?
58 = ?
59 = ?
60 = ?
61 = ?
62 = ?
63 = 8 * 8 - 8 / 8
64 = 8 * 8 * 8 / 8
65 = 8 * 8 + 8 / 8
66 = ?
67 = ?
68 = ?
69 = ?
70 = ?
71 = ?
72 = (8 + 8 / 8) * 8
73 = ?
74 = ? 
75 = ?
76 = ?
77 = ?
78 = ?
79 = ?
80 = 8 * 8 + 8 + 8
81 = ?
82 = ?
83 = ?
84 = ?
85 = ?
86 = ?
87 = 88 - 8 / 8
88 = 88 * 8 / 8
89 = 88 + 8 / 8
90 = ?
91 = ?
92 = ?
93 = ?
94 = ?
95 = ?
96 = ?
97 = ?
98 = ?
99 = ?
100 = ?
```

(Thank you to Joe for the help with 6, 8 and 10, and kushj for the some of the 11-100 entries)

I do have some questions regarding the rules, though - because if we're allowed some fun takes on the 'exponents' rule, these kind of approaches become feasible:

```
6  = 8 - Log8(8 * 8)
10 = 8 + Log8(8 * 8)
```

Having the sqrt operator would be very useful too, but I don't know whether it's allowed.

```
5  = Sqrt(8 + 8) + (8 / 8)
8  = Sqrt(8 * 8) * (8 / 8)
```

Please do tell me whether these two operators are allowed for the puzzle.

Comment: 8  =  ( 8 ^ (8 - 8) ) * 8

Comment: Also:  6 = 8 - ( 8 + 8 ) / 8 ;  10 = 8 + ( 8 + 8 ) / 8

Comment: 10 = (88 - 8)/8, if "concatenation" counts

Comment: Are we allowed decimals? $\frac{8}{.8} + \frac{8}{8} = 11$

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a script to generate quick answer using only brackets and 4 basic operators.

Now on to much more interesting task to generate rest of numbers!

> 1  :  (8 + 8 - 8) / 8
>     2  :  8 / 8 + 8 / 8
>     3  :  (8 + 8 + 8) / 8
>     4  :  8 / (8 + 8) * 8
>     5  : ?
>     6  :  8 - (8 + 8) / 8
>     7  :  (8 * 8 - 8) / 8
>     8  :  8 + (8 - 8) * 8
>     9  :  (8 + 8 * 8) / 8
>     10  :  8 + (8 + 8) / 8
>     11  : ?
>     12  : ?
>     13  : ?
>     14  : ?
>     15  :  8 + 8 - 8 / 8
>     16  :  8 + 8 + 8 - 8
>     17  :  8 + 8 + 8 / 8
>     18  : ?
>     19  : ?
>     20  : ?
>     21  : ?
>     22  : ?
>     23  : ?
>     24  : ?
>     25  : ?
>     26  : ?
>     27  : ?
>     28  : ?
>     29  : ?
>     30  : ?
>     31  : ?
>     32  :  8 + 8 + 8 + 8
>     33  : ?
>     34  : ?
>     35  : ?
>     36  : ?
>     37  : ?
>     38  : ?
>     39  : ?
>     40  : ?
>     41  : ?
>     42  : ?
>     43  : ?
>     44  : ?
>     45  : ?
>     46  : ?
>     47  : ?
>     48  :  8 * 8 - 8 - 8
>     49  : ?
>     50  : ?
>     51  : ?
>     52  : ?
>     53  : ?
>     54  : ?
>     55  : ?
>     56  :  (8 - 8 / 8) * 8
>     57  : ?
>     58  : ?
>     59  : ?
>     60  : ?
>     61  : ?
>     62  : ?
>     63  :  8 * 8 - 8 / 8
>     64  :  (8 + 8 - 8) * 8
>     65  :  8 * 8 + 8 / 8
>     66  : ?
>     67  : ?
>     68  : ?
>     69  : ?
>     70  : ?
>     71  : ?
>     72  :  (8 + 8 / 8) * 8
>     73  : ?
>     74  : ?
>     75  : ?
>     76  : ?
>     77  : ?
>     78  : ?
>     79  : ?
>     80  :  8 + 8 + 8 * 8
>     81  : ?
>     82  : ?
>     83  : ?
>     84  : ?
>     85  : ?
>     86  : ?
>     87  : ?
>     88  : ?
>     89  : ?
>     90  : ?
>     91  : ?
>     92  : ?
>     93  : ?
>     94  : ?
>     95  : ?
>     96  : ?
>     97  : ?
>     98  : ?
>     99  : ?
>     100  : ?